# Recursive procedure for getting child records in hierarchical dataset

Tags: delphi, recursion

I have a data table (MDTasks) that has records represented in a tree view.  Each record has a unique field, 'ID', and a field 'Parent_ID', which refers to the ID of the parent.  I am trying to make a list of all the children at any level of a record with a given ID.  I have the following, which gets the first child at each level, but doesn't go back up to get the siblings at any level.  I would be grateful for any help.  Thank you.

```
procedure TfmList.GetChildren(TaskID: integer);
var
  iChildID: integer;
begin
  with MDTasks do
  begin
    first;
    while not EOF do
    begin
      if FieldByName('Parent_ID').AsInteger = TaskID then
      begin
        iChildID := FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;
        Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(iChildID));
        GetChildren(iChildID);
      end;
      next;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Is your MDTasks table one that accesses a Sql server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should do what you want, if I understand you correctly.  It uses a ClientDataSet so that my answer is self contained and so that the test data can easily be set up.

It uses a call to `CloneCursor` to do the recursive search for the children of the specified parent node ID.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CDS1.CreateDataSet;
  CDS1.InsertRecord([1, -1]);
  CDS1.InsertRecord([2, -1]);
  CDS1.InsertRecord([3, -1]);
  CDS1.InsertRecord([4, 2]);  //  This and the following rows are all children of ID = 2 
  CDS1.InsertRecord([5, 2]);
  CDS1.InsertRecord([6, 4]);
  CDS1.InsertRecord([7, 4]);
  CDS1.InsertRecord([8, 7]);

  FindChildren(2);
end;

procedure TForm1.FindChildren(ParentID : Integer);

  procedure FindChildrenInner(ParentID : Integer);
  var
    TempCDS : TClientDataSet;
    ID : Integer;
  begin
    TempCDS := TClientDataSet.Create(Nil);
    try
      TempCDS.CloneCursor(CDS1, False, True);
      TempCDS.First;
      while not TempCDS.Eof do begin
        if TempCDS.FieldByName('Parent_ID').AsInteger = ParentID then begin
          ID := TempCDS.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;
          Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('ID: %d, Parent: %d', [ID, ParentID]));
          FindChildrenInner(ID);
        end;
        TempCDS.Next;
      end;
    finally
      TempCDS.Free;
    end;
  end;

begin
  Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  try
    Memo1.Lines.Clear;
    Assert(CDS1.Locate('ID', ParentID, []));
    FindChildrenInner(ParentID);
  finally
    Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, I would say that it gets all the childs at the last level (not only first one). The problem is that you "share" the dataset (`MDTasks`) between levels - so when the last level iterates to the end of the table and returns to the caller the `while not EOF do` evaluates to `false` (on the parent level now) and loop ends, thus only the first child is gotten on levels above the last one.

One solution would be to iterate each level fully, logging `Parent_ID`s into local array, then use that array to get the next level below it.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is probably to use bookmarks in the table MDTasks. Let your procedure set a bookmark at the beginning and return to this bookmark at the end so the position/cursor in MDTasks is not changed from GetChildren.

Answer (score -1):

your problem is that you are calling recursive function against the same data. you can use filtering, for example:

```
procedure GoGoGo (Id: integer);
var
  OldFilter: string;
begin
  OldFilter := Table.Filter;
  Table.Filter := 'ParentId = ' + IntToStr (Id);
  try
    Table.First;
    while not Table.Eof do begin
      Memo.Lines.Add (Format('ID: %d, Parent: %d', 
        [Table.FieldByName ('I'd).AsInteger, 
         Table.FieldByName ('ParentID').AsInteger]));
      GoGoGo (Table.FieldByName ('Id').AsInteger);
      if Table.Locate ('Id', Id, []) then
        Table.Next;
    end;
  finally
    Table.Filter := OldFilter;
  end;
end;

<...>
Memo.Lines.Clear;
Table.Filtered := TRUE;
Table.First;
GoGoGo (Table.FieldByName ('Id').AsInteger);
```

haven't tested this code, it may contain errors, but hopefully, idea is quite clear. with the same idea you can use another approaches, like create new TQuery with dynamically generated where clause, etc. I'm not a fan of such things just because in a really big tree, creating new objects in every iteration of recursive function may result in a stack overflow.

gl there ;)

Comment: "creating new objects in every iteration of recursive function may result in a stack overflow. "  It's rather ironic that you should say that, because executing your code (after correction of errors like the two field names) against the test data in my answer results in exactly that, a stack overflow!

Comment: that means, that function falls into endless loop because of logic errors. when you are creating objects in recursive function - it will end with SO because of memory usage. i will try to check my code :)

Comment: That's why I asked the OP if he is using a Sql Server.  If he is, he can do it all in SQL and let the server overflow *its* stack instead of his ;=)

Comment: I appreciate the interest. No, it's not SQL - just a TTable derivative (Developer Express TMemData).